# Internet Explorer 8(Default) Issue, Chrome is Ok

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml, ie

I have created CAML query. Below is the code for searching list item.

```
<input type="text" style="width:350px" id="txtSearch" />
<dl class="dropdown"> 
<dt>

<a href="#">

  <span class="hida">Select Country</span>    

  <p class="multiSel"></p>  

</a>

</dt>



<dd>

    <div class="mutliSelect">

        <ul>

            <li>

                <input name='country' type="checkbox" value="Kenya" />Kenya 
</li>

            <li>

                <input name='country' type="checkbox" value="Ethiopia" 
/>Ethiopia</li>

            <li>

                <input name='country' type="checkbox" value="Uganda" 
/>Uganda</li>

            <li>

                <input name='country' type="checkbox" value="Morocco" 
/>Morocco</li>

            <li>

                <input name='country' type="checkbox" value="Sudan" 
/>Sudan</li>

            <li>

                <input name='country' type="checkbox" value="Somalia" 
/>Somalia</li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</dd>

  <!-- <button>Filter</button> -->

</dl>




<style>





.dropdown {

  padding-left: 500px;

}




a {

  /* color: #fff; */

}

.dropdown dd,

   .dropdown dt {

  margin: 0px;

  padding: 0px;

}

 .dropdown ul {

  margin: -1px 0 0 0;

}


 .dropdown dd {

  position: relative;

}

 .dropdown a,

.dropdown a:visited {

color: #fff; 

  text-decoration: none;

  outline: none;

  font-size: 12px;

}




    .dropdown dt a {

   background-color: #4F6877; 

  display: block;

  padding: 8px 20px 5px 10px;

 min-height: 25px;

  line-height: 24px;

  overflow: hidden;

  border: 0;

  width: 272px;

}


  .dropdown dt a span,

.multiSel span {

  cursor: pointer;

  display: inline-block;

  padding: 0 3px 2px 0;

}

   .dropdown dd ul {

  background-color: #4F6877;

  border: 0;

  color: #fff;

  display: none;

  left: 0px;

  padding: 2px 15px 2px 5px;

  position: absolute;

 top: 2px;

 width: 280px;

  list-style: none;

  height: 100px;

  overflow: auto;

}


   .dropdown span.value {

  display: none;

}


.dropdown dd ul li a {

  padding: 5px;

 display: block;

}


    .dropdown dd ul li a:hover {

  background-color: #fff;

}


</style>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

 <script>


    $(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function() {

  $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');

});




    $(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {

  $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();

});




function getSelectedValue(id) {

  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();

}




$(document).bind('click', function(e) {

 var $clicked = $(e.target);

  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();

});




$('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {




  var title = 
$(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),

title = $(this).val() + ",";




  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';

    $('.multiSel').append(html);

    $(".hida").hide();

  } else {

    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();

    var ret = $(".hida");

    $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);




  }

});

</script>
    <input type="button" style=" font-size:20px;font-family:'Segoe UI 
    Light','Segoe UI','Segoe',Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background- 
   color:#0072C6; color:white" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="return 
    search(); return false" />

<style>
.highlight {
background-color: #FFFF88;
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=".../SiteAssets/jquery-
1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 /*
 *This is jQuery Highlight plugin to highlight the result text

 */

jQuery.extend({
highlight: function (node, re, nodeName, className) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var match = node.data.match(re);
        if (match) {
            var highlight = document.createElement(nodeName || 'span');
            highlight.className = className || 'highlight';
            var wordNode = node.splitText(match.index);
            wordNode.splitText(match[0].length);
            var wordClone = wordNode.cloneNode(true);
            highlight.appendChild(wordClone);
            wordNode.parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, wordNode);
            return 1; //skip added node in parent
        }
    } else if ((node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes) && // only element 
nodes that have children
            !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName) && // ignore script and 
style nodes
            !(node.tagName === nodeName.toUpperCase() && node.className === 
className)) { // skip if already highlighted
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re, nodeName, 
className);
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
});

jQuery.fn.unhighlight = function (options) {
var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span' };
jQuery.extend(settings, options);

return this.find(settings.element + "." + settings.className).each(function 
() {
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    parent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
    parent.normalize();
}).end();
};

jQuery.fn.highlight = function (words, options) {
var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span', caseSensitive:  
   false, wordsOnly: false };
jQuery.extend(settings, options);

if (words.constructor === String) {
    words = [words];
}
words = jQuery.grep(words, function(word, i){
  return word != '';
});
words = jQuery.map(words, function(word, i) {
  return word.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"); 
});
if (words.length == 0) { return this; };

var flag = settings.caseSensitive ? "" : "i";
var pattern = "(" + words.join("|") + ")";
if (settings.wordsOnly) {
    pattern = "\\b" + pattern + "\\b";
}
var re = new RegExp(pattern, flag);

return this.each(function () {
    jQuery.highlight(this, re, settings.element, settings.className);
});
};

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function search()

      {
        var checkedValues = '';
        $('input[name="country"]:checked').each(function() {
           console.log(this.value);
           checkedValues += "<Value Type='text'>" + $(this).val() + "
</Value>";
        });

      var Countryqry= ''; /* document.getElementById("Countryqry").value; */
       $("#tasksUL").empty();
      var qry= document.getElementById("txtSearch").value
  var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems 
xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>Project Inventory</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='LinkTitleNoMenu' /> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Country' /> \
                           <FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' /> \
 <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
  </viewFields> \
  <query> \
   <Query> \
   <Where> \
  <And> \
     <In> \
        <FieldRef Name='Country' /> \
        <Values>"+checkedValues+"</Values>\
     </In> \
     <Or> \
        <Contains> \
           <FieldRef Name='LinkTitleNoMenu' /> \
           <Value Type='Computed'>"+qry+"</Value> \
        </Contains> \
        <Contains> \
           <FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' /> \
           <Value Type='Computed'>"+qry+"</Value> \
        </Contains> \
     </Or> \
  </And> \
   </Where> \
    </Query> \
  </query> \
   </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";       

     $.ajax({
        url: ".../InformationTechnology/sb1/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });

  }

    function processResult(xData, status) {
// show searching text and image when search button is clicked
var loadhtml="<div id='loading' class='ms-dlgLoadingTextDiv'><span 
style='padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 10px;'><img width='24' height='24' 
title='This animation indicates the operation is in progress. Click to 
remove this animated image.' src='/_layouts/15/images/gears_anv4.gif?
rev=36'/></span><span class='ms-core-pageTitle ms-accentText'>Searching...
</span></div>";

//var totalRows = $(xData.responseXML).find("rs\\:data").attr("ItemCount");
var totalRows =   getZRows(xData.responseXML);
if(totalRows=="0")
{
 $("#loading").remove();
$("#tasksUL").before("<div  id='loading'  style='color:red;font-
size:15px'>No matching records found. Please refine your search.</div>");
return true;
}
$("#tasksUL").before(loadhtml);
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function() {
// creating hyperlink for each item to display form of that list item
var lnk="<a 
href='.../InformationTechnology/sb1/Lists/Project%20Inventory/DispForm.aspx?
ID=" + $(this).attr('ows_ID') + 
"&source=.../InformationTechnology/sb1/default.aspx'>"+ 
$(this).attr("ows_Title") +"</a>";

        var liHtml = "<li>"+ lnk+"</li>";

// 2 second delay and show searching text and image also highlight the 
   result with the searched keyword
setTimeout(function(){
 $("#loading").remove();
  $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
  $("#tasksUL > li").highlight(document.getElementById("txtSearch").value);
}, 2000);

    });

}


$(document).ready(function(){
// check if enter button is pressed and then search button clicked event is 
   called
$('#txtSearch').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==13)
 { $('#btnSearch').click();return false;}
});
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getZRows(rXML) {
  var rows;
  var itemCount = $(rXML).find("rs\\:data").attr("ItemCount");
  if (rXML.getElementsByTagName("z:row").length == 0 && itemCount == 
undefined) {
   rows = rXML.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "row");
  } else {
  rows = rXML.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
  }
  return rows.length;
 }
</script>

<div id="search_result">
<ul id="tasksUL"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Chrom is oK, But IE got an issue ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagNameNS'

Comment: When I changed the Document mode to "Edge" or more than IE8, it works. But, My default IE is 8

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't support getElementsByTagNameNS. getElementsByTagName should work in IE8. You can find more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753080/alternative-to-getelementsbytagnamens-when-running-in-ie8) (and in the comments therein)